# fastlane: Deploy to local iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fastlane

I am using fastlane to manage provisioning profiles, push builds to TestFlight etc. but now I was wondering if it is possible to deploy on my local (USB) iOS device by any fastlane command or pipeline?

Especially deploying a React Native app to the local device via fastlane would be awesome?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such option yet, at least that I am aware of.

You can see all the available fastlane commands, "actions" using fastlane's terminology, by typing `fastlane actions`.

One tool you can use to deploy an app to a connected device from the terminal is to use [`ios-deploy`](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy).

You could build the app using fastlane's `gym`, then run `ios-deploy`.

The tool is distributed via [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com). If you are keen on keeping your toolchain Ruby only, there is a gem wrapping it [`ios-deploy-gem`](https://github.com/mokagio/ios-deploy-gem), which might not bu up-to-date though.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try it out and update this post if it fits my requirements or if I need some more help.

Comment: @WalterMartinVargas-Pena scan is a tool to run unit tests. I think scan might be able to run tests on a connected device, but then the app is killed. What sebbo is asking seems more on the lines of actually launching the app on a connected device via CLI.